# Search for phrase within left and right bounds

Tags: python, regex

It will be better if I show what I mean.

Here are some selections from a data set I am parsing:

> 1.【ひろゆき】万能ねぎとわけぎと記憶力。**Grimbergen blonde**を呑みながら。2020/12/18 V23
>
> 2.【ひろゆき】日本酒は鮮度が大事ですよ。  **獺祭**を呑みながら 2019/02/11
>
> 3.【ひろゆき】聞かれたことに答えてみようの回。**Cheshire Chocolate Porter**飲みつつ。
>
> 4.【ひろゆき】早起きは得しないし、体に悪いよね。。**Lagunitas IPA**を呑みながら 2019/04/14 D23
>
> I am trying to grab the name of the beverege. In 1 it is "Grimbergen
> blonde", in 2 "獺祭" it is in 3 it is "Cheshire Chocolate Porter", in 4
> it is "Lagunitas IPA"

I have tried using the following pattern:

```
pattern = re.compile('(?<=[\？。！]).*(?=を[飲呑])')
```

I see that the drink is always immediately followed by `を` or `呑` / `飲`. I also see that the drink is always immediately after `。` or `？`.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[EDIT]**
Would you please try the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import re
import sys, codecs

sys.stdout = codecs.getwriter('utf_8')(sys.stdout)

str = u"""
1.【ひろゆき】万能ねぎとわけぎと記憶力。Grimbergen blondeを呑みながら。2020/12/18 V23

2.【ひろゆき】日本酒は鮮度が大事ですよ。 獺祭を呑みながら 2019/02/11

3.【ひろゆき】聞かれたことに答えてみようの回。Cheshire Chocolate Porter飲みつつ。

4.【ひろゆき】早起きは得しないし、体に悪いよね。。Lagunitas IPAを呑みながら 2019/04/14 D23
5.【ひろゆき】冬将軍強くね？温暖化どこいったの？ PARISIS NOËLを呑みつつ 2019/01/26
6.【ひろゆき】運のいい人っているよね。科学的根拠ないけど。。LA VIRGEN MADRID LAGERを呑みながら  2020/01/16 J08
"""

m = re.finditer(ur'.*[。？]+\s?(.*?)を?[呑飲]', str)
for i in m:
    print(i.group(1))
```

Result:

```
Grimbergen blonde
獺祭
Cheshire Chocolate Porter
Lagunitas IPA
PARISIS NOËL
LA VIRGEN MADRID LAGER
```

Explanation of the regex `'.*[。？]+\s?(.*?)を?[呑飲]'`:

- The first `.*` matches as long as possible then backtracks to try the following regex matches.
- `[。？]+` matches one or more sequence of Japanese period or question mark.
- `\s?` matches a blank character if any. It removes leading white spaces
  before the name of the beverage.
- The `?` in the `(.*?)` enables the shortest (non-greedy) match and
  the capture group is assigned to the matched substring.
- `を?` matches a character "を" if any considering the case the
  postpositional particle "を" is sometimes omitted in Japasene.
- `[呑飲]` matches either character which are variation of Kanji
  meaning "to drink".

In the previous post, the leading `.*` was missing and allowed an excess match.
Now the regex once increments the pointer as much as possible then backtracks
from right to left. That is why the unnecessary substring is removed now.

Comment: This is working quite well. I have come across this issue though, that I did not forsee: ['温暖化どこいったの？ PARISIS NOËL'] The regex cannot catch two instances of question marks or periods. How can I only get the first instance coming from the right? Ie, in this case, right after "P"?

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. Can I expect the beverage name `PARISIS NOËL` is followed by the keyword e.g. `を呑みながら` as well as other examples?

Comment: Yes. The full sentence is: 【ひろゆき】冬将軍強くね？温暖化どこいったの？ PARISIS NOËLを呑みつつ 2019/01/26      . Another issue I found was with:                                
       【ひろゆき】運のいい人っているよね。科学的根拠ないけど。。LA VIRGEN MADRID LAGERを呑みながら 2020/01/16 J08        -> matching "科学的根拠ないけど。。LA VIRGEN MADRID LAGER'"

Comment: Thank you for the prompt and comprehensive reply. I've updated my answer accordingly. How about then?

Comment: Thank you so much! Would you mind explaining it a bit? I think I understand that we are using .* in the beginning to get through all of the initial text, then checking if there is a period or question mark with [。？], and then an optional space. After that we are getting the actual group with (.*?). Why is that non-greedy here?

Comment: I've added the explanation of the regex in my answer. I should have done it earlier :)

Comment: Honestly thank you so much for taking your time to do this. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

We can use a `[|]` for an `or` statement in our lookahead to check for either of the two following chars.

```
re.findall(r'(?<=。)[^。].*(?=[を|飲])', string)

#['Grimbergen blonde', ' 獺祭', 'Cheshire Chocolate Porter', 'Lagunitas IPA']
```

---

Breakdown

1. `(?<=。)` - Check if `。` occurs before our search, look behind.
2. `[^。].*` - Match all excluding `。` This accounts for the double `。。` before Lagunitas
3. `(?=[を|飲])` - Look ahead to see if any of the characters directly follow our match all

You can find a further breakdown [here](https://regex101.com/r/WgAFQj/1)